# HTT response code and Status code in mail by python

Tags: python, python-2.7, email

We have out own portal which is designed in .ASP. And in that portal there are multiple tabs.
To monitor each page and their loading time (to monitor slowness of each page) I have below code.

I have copied all the .asp pages in one notepad and this script fetches each one to monitor.
(Hoping httpauth works)
When I tried to send email if status code is other than 200 and time taken more than 0.5 sec it will shoot mail
But for each URL it sends different mail, also it only gives URL in subject line.
How do I make like to send only one mail including all errors with respective urls.

```
i.e.
https://example.org/node.asp - status 404
https://example.org/frame.asp - response time is 2 sec.
https://example.org/ticketgen.asp - response time is 5 sec.
https://example.org/alert.asp - status 500
```

Below is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pickle, os, sys, logging
from httplib import HTTPConnection, socket
from smtplib import SMTP
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests

def get_response_time(url):
    return requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'secpasswd')).elapsed.total_seconds()

def email_alert(message, status):
    fromaddr = 'abc@mysite.com'
    toaddrs = 'xyz@mysite.com'

    server = SMTP('smtp.office365.com')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(fromaddr, 'mypasswd')
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, 'Subject: %s\r\n%s' % (status, message))
    server.quit()

def get_site_status(url):
    response = get_response(url)
   try:
        if response == 200:
            return 'up'
   except AttributeError:
        pass
    return 'down'

def get_response(url):
    '''Return response object from URL'''
    try:
        conn = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'secpasswd'))
        #conn.request('HEAD', '/')
        return conn.status_code
    except socket.error:
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        logging.error('Bad URL:{}'.format( url))
        exit(1)

def get_headers(url):
    '''Gets all headers from URL request and returns'''
    response = get_response(url)
    try:
        return getattr(response, 'getheaders')()
    except AttributeError:
        return 'Headers unavailable'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    content = []
    with open("/home/support/url_list.txt") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    for url in content:
        url = url.strip()
        r_time = get_response_time(url)
        print(r_time)
        if r_time > 0.5 :
        #print("Please send email", url, "as Response Time is", r_time)
         email_alert(str(r_time), url)

    status = get_site_status(url)
    if status == "down":
        #print("Send email", url, "is", status, "and Response is", get_response(url))
        email_alert(str(get_site_status(url)), url)
```

Comment: Do you want to send one email per each run i.e do you want to read full `/home/support/url_list.txt` , process it and then send just one email?

Comment: Yes I want to read full `/home/support/url_list.txt` process it and then send one mail containing list of url's which are taking more than 0.5 sec and url's which are having status code other than 200

Answer (score 1):

Instead of executing `email_alert(str(r_time), url)` for each url, what you can do is to cache each url with response time in responses dict. And create email message after  `for url in content` loop. i.e

```
res_times = {}
for url in content:
    url = url.strip()
    r_time = get_response_time(url)
    print(r_time)
    if r_time > 0.5 :
       res_times[url] = r_time

message = ''
#res_times not empty means you have to send error email
for x in res_times.items():
     message += "Url: %s, response time: %s\n" % x
if message:
    email_alert(message, 'error')
```

Comment: Not working, in subject `error` this words occurs. And nothing in message body.

Comment: Well.. this was a code snippet to show you general idea, not tested code that you can copy-paste to your script. It probably contains some errors (e.g in calling email_alert) but general idea is to 1) collect error message for all requests 2) send only one email with full error message.

Comment: yes, When I print `message` it shows all those URLS which are above 0.5 sec, but not working in `email_alert`

Comment: So you're almost there. Just check why does your `email_alert` function does not put massege to mail body if message has more than one line.

Comment: Not sure why `email_alert` function doesn't put message to mail body, but I found workaround for this. I put `message` variable into html file and attached to mail body. However `status = get_site_status(url)` is still not working hoping I would find solution for this as well.

Comment: Great :). So If you find my answer useful, please upvote or accept it.